# Django -> Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following view which works perfectly:

```
@transaction.atomic
def register(request):
    next_url = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', reverse('profile')))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        profileform = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()

            # Login the newly created user.
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username,
                                              password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            login(request, authenticated_user)
            return redirect(next_url)
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        profileform = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'meta/register.html', {'form': form, 'profileform': profileform, 'next': next_url})
```

However, when I wish to save the additional profile information using the following line (placed below the line new_user = form.save() ):

```
    new_user_profile = profileform.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
```

My model for the profile is as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=8)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'fbf_profile'
```

Any help would be great, Alan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with foreign keys like this you typically see a save with `commit=False` and then setting the foreign keys on the model manually.  e.g.,

```
new_user = form.save()
profile = profileform.save(commit=False)
if profile.user_id is None:
    profile.user_id = new_user.id
profile.save()
```

> This `save()` method accepts an optional `commit` keyword argument, which accepts either `True` or `False`. If you call `save()` with `commit=False`, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. In this case, it’s up to you to call `save()` on the resulting model instance. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on the object before saving it, or if you want to use one of the specialized model saving options. `commit` is `True` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation alongside the answer.  Helps the old knowledge bank.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `user` field is not set in the `ProfileForm`. The `Profile` model needs a `user_id` for the `user` `OneToOneField`.

The `ProfileForm` will need a `user` field that you'll have to set, or you'll have to manually set the `user` field in the `save()` function of `ProfileForm` (which you would then have to override).